# Explanation of derivative notation

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

I know how derivatives work. However I always avoided the $$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} x}$$ notation.  I've seen the other posts on this but not with an example. This is from my textbook and maybe someone can explain the terms and how they are being used here:

$$
t_{i}(x):=\frac{x-x_{i}}{x_{i+1}-x_{i}} \in[0 ; 1]=\frac{x-x_{i}}{h_{i}} \in[0 ; 1]
$$
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} x}\left(f\left(t_{i}(x)\right)\right)=\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} t}\left(f\left(t_{i}(x)\right)\right) \cdot \frac{\mathrm{d} t_i}{\mathrm{~d} x}=\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} t}\left(f\left(t_{i}(x)\right)\right) \cdot \frac{1}{x_{i+1}-x_{i}}=\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} t}\left(f\left(t_{i}(x)\right)\right) \cdot \frac{1}{h_{i}}
$$

Comment: More context would be good. What is $t_i$? What has this to do with integration?

Comment: Note: you can declare `\newcommand{\d}{\mathrm{d}}` and then write `$\frac{\d}{\d x}$` for convenience

Comment: which textbook is this from?

Comment: @FShrike I added the function for context

Comment: $\frac{d}{dt}$ is a verb. It tells you to take the derivative of some object.

Comment: $\newcommand{\d}{\mathrm{d}}$In general, $$\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{\mathrm{d}v}$$ 
refers to the derivative of some variable, function or otherwise w.r.t some variable, function or otherwise $v$. Here, they are using the chain rule. You're probably more familiar with: $$(f(g(x)))'=f'(g(x)\cdot g'(x)$$But in Leibniz notation this is:$$\frac{d}{dx}[f(g(x))]=\frac{\d f}{\d g}\cdot\frac{\d g}{\d x}$$Which for many is more intuitive, as it appears as if the fractions cancel out. That's what this textbook is using, except where they write $\frac{\d t}{\d x}$ they should have perhaps written $\d t_i$

Comment: It looks like someone has taken a domain of x, and has partitioned it.  $h_i$ represents the width of partition $i.$  $t$ gives a value a point inside the partition.  i.e. you are $t\%$ of the way between the boundaries of the partition.  $f(t)$ has a domain of $[0,1)$ and $f(t(x))$ would have a sort of quasi-periodicity.  And finally, how do we calculate how much $f(t_i(x))$ is changing as $x$ changes?  It is the sensitivity of $f$ to changes in $t$ divided by the width of the partition.

Comment: There is an inconsistency in the notation, $t\leftrightarrow t_i$.